# PDO Transaction not writing to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO transaction script that is not working.

I open the connection with:

```
<?php
$DBhost="localhost";
$DBuser="userid";  These are set properly
$DBpassword="password";  These are set properly

try {
    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost; charset=utf8", $DBuser, $DBpassword);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm then creating an array of the sql statements that I need to have executed.  They all execute fine when manually run in phpMyAdmin.

So here is my transaction code:

```
try {
    echo "size of sql = " . sizeof($sql) . "<br />";
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($sql); $i++){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql[$i]);
        $stmt->execute($sql[$i]);
        echo "executing " . $sql[$i] . "<br />\r\n";
    }
    $conn->commit();
    $message = "Player successfully updated !!";
    $json = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message);
    $json_data = json_encode($json);
    echo $json_data;
    return;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $conn->rollback();
    $message = "Could not process transaction.  Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    $json = array('status' => 'failure', 'message' => $message);
    $json_data = json_encode($json);
    echo $json_data;
    return;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
size of sql = 7
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', 'Player ID # 1812(Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) name had changed from Brady Jr., Tom to Brady, Tom')
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', 'Player ID # 1812(Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) tm_id had changed from 9022 to 9003')
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', 'Player ID # 1812(Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) pos had changed from LB to QB')
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', Player ID # 1812 (Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) has changed eligible positions from QB, R, LB, DEF to QB, RB, R, K)
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', 'Player ID # 1812(Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) active had changed from 0 to 1')
executing INSERT INTO bowlingt_lg_shared.player_changes (change_date, change_text) VALUES ('2016-06-21', 'Player ID # 1812(Brady Jr., Tom - LB - MIN) tm_abbr had changed from MIN to NE')
executing UPDATE bowlingt_lg_shared.players SET Name = 'Brady, Tom', tm_id = 9003, pos = 'QB', elig_pos = 'QB, RB, R, K', active = 1 WHERE id = 1812
{"status":"success","message":"Player successfully updated !!"}
```

So it thinks it has executed all the SQL statements correctly, but does not process them to the database.   I've very new to PDO, but I've used MySQL & mysqli without issues for years.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (!$conn->commit();) {
    $message = "Transaction commit failed");
} else { $message = "Player successfully updated !!";}`

Comment: there is no exception if commit failed I guess.

Comment: They shouldn't be. Your 4th query is missing quotes, which makes it a syntax error, which SHOULD have thrown an exception on the prepare phase.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the `execute()` call. The parameters are only needed when you have an array of input values for parameter markers, which you don't. When you call `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql[$i])`, php associates the correct `$sql` statement with the `$stmt` variable, and it will get overwritten with each successive call. Change the following:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql[$i]);
 $stmt->execute($sql[$i]);
```

to:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql[$i]);
 $stmt->execute();
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer...

```
    $stmt->execute($sql[$i]);
```

simply needed to be:

```
    $stmt->execute();
```

That seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: In fact, you don't need execute at all. Just run query() instead of prepare execute